# No Unsubscribe message after unsubscribe newsletter Magento 2

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I have set up newsletters in my magento website.

There is **Unsubscribe** link in newsletter email which works perfectly i.e. customer is unsubscribed from newsletter.

But when customer click on unsubscribe link in newsletter email, he is redirected to home page of website with no message. So customer don't get idea about his unsubscription done or not!

How can i show message to customer that he has unsubscribed successfully?

Comment: without redirecting to account page it is possible to show message on home page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by setting redirection to **Customer Account** page once user is unsubscribed instead of redirecting him to **Home** page!

Comment: How you set redirection to Customer Account page?please share your answer.

Comment: @SmitaKagwade, could you redirect to customer account page?